# Typescript error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.AppleDouble'

Tags: node.js, macos, typescript

I am working on a NodeJS project which uses TypeScript on my Mac with OSX 10.12.6 The project is on a network share which runs on a RPI (cannot develop local because of connected hardware on the RPI).

When I run `tsc -p tsconfig.json` I get:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.AppleDouble'.
```

Since I am working on a network share it turns out all folders are polluted with `.AppleDouble` files.

After removing these files using:

```
find . -name '.AppleDouble' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

I can compile without a problem. The thing is OSX keeps writing these '.AppleDouble' files to my network share.

In older versions of OSX you could disable this by using:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true
```

or

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

However it looks like these are not working anymore in OSX 10.12. There are tools like BlueHarvest but these do not *prevent* the creation but only removes them automatically.

Does anyone know a solution in how I can either prevent the creation of `.AppleDouble` files on network share or make the Typescript compiler work so it ignores the `.AppleDouble`?

**My tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "rootDir": "src-ts",
        "outDir": "build"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "build",
        "node_modules",
        ".AppleDouble"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not my preferred solution, but it made it at least workable:

It turned out I used Netatalk on my server to share my project folder over the network via AFP. It turns out AFP keeps writing the `.AppleDouble` files to the network share.

I switched to using Samba for the sharing the folder and OSX did not write any `.AppleDouble` files anymore to the share.

To remove the all `.AppleDouble` files recursively use:

`find ./ -depth -name ".AppleDouble" -exec rm -Rf {} \;`